# Git rebase/master changes from branch into master

Tags: git, git-rebase

Two weeks ago, I created a new branch, let's call it `exp`. During this time there have been several commits both in `exp` and in `master`. During this time `exp` has not been updated with the changes from `master`

Now I want to get all the changes from `exp` into master, without losing my whole history (i.e. I don't want to just have one commit in `master` with all the changes, but rather that all my commits in `exp` appear in the history of `master`)

How is this possible? I've looked into [Rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Rebasing) but when I do:

```
git checkout exp
git rebase master
```

At the end of the process I am in `exp` and when I `git status` I see all the commits I have made in `exp` as if I wanted to push them into `exp` again

Comment: why rebase? why not merge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your goal is to have all the commits in `exp` in `master`'s history and retain all of your commits. You can achieve this regardless of whether you use `git merge` or `git rebase`.

**MERGE:**

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout exp
git merge master
git push -u origin exp
```

Make to perform step 2 so that you pull the latest `master` and have the latest changes.

**REBASE:**

```
git checkout exp
git pull --rebase origin master
git push -u origin exp
```

If you do not want to update your local `master` in the process, you can alternatively perform the following steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout exp
git rebase master
git push -u origin exp
```

Note that when you `git pull --rebase origin master`, you are basing your changes on the latest version of `origin`'s `master`. Also, this command does not update your local copy of `master`.

**NOTE:** You might need to force push (`git push -f origin exp`) if you are using `git rebase`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simply do merge your `exp` branch to your `master`. You would still have all your history and as a bonus you would keep all your original commit times.

```
git checkout master
git merge exp
```

If you **really** want to go with the `rebase` option, then you just need to merge your rebased `exp` branch to `master`.

```
git checkout exp
git rebase master

git checkout master
git merge exp
```

**NOTE:** With the merge (first) option, you would end up with a *no-fast-forward* merge (additional commit for your merge) because your branches probably have diverged. If you are GitHub's pull request user, it uses this kind of merges. If you want to do the same with your second (`rebase`) option, you can add `--no-ff` option to your merge command.

```
git merge exp --no-ff
```